# How to enable/Disable a drop down list , based on other drop down value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

I have the following two drop down lists inside my asp.net MVC web application:-

```
<div>

   <span class="f">Role</span>

     @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Server.RoleID, ((IEnumerable<TMS.Models.TechnologyRole>)ViewBag.TechRole).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Name), 
        Value = option.RoleID.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model.Server != null) && (option.RoleID == Model.Server.RoleID)
    }), "Choose...")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.RoleID)
</div>
<div>
   <span class="f">Virtual Center</span>

     @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Server.VirtualCenterID, ((IEnumerable<TMS.Models.TMSServer>)ViewBag.Servers).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Technology.Tag), 
        Value = option.TMSServerID.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model.Server != null) && (Model.Server != null) && (option.TMSServerID == Model.Server.VirtualCenterID)
    }), "Choose...")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.VirtualCenterID)
</div>
```

Now I need the following:-

1. To enable the Virtual Centre drop down list only if the Role drop down list value = “Virtual Server”.
2. Incase the user deselect the “Virtual Server” values, to clear the selection for the Virtual center drop downlist and disable it.

Can anyone advice how I can implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

For 1:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Server.VirtualCenterID, ..., new { disabled = "disabled" })

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("selectorForFirstDropDown").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "Virtual Server") {
                $("selectorForSecondDropDown").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else {
                $("selectorForSecondDropDown").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
    });
```

Sample:

```
// Model
public class model
{
    public string first { get; set; }
    public string second { get; set; }
}

// Controller
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.List = new List<Tuple<string, string>>()
    {
        new Tuple<string, string>("1", "a"),
        new Tuple<string, string>("2", "b"),
        new Tuple<string, string>("3", "c"),
    };

    return View();
}

// View
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.first, new SelectList(ViewBag.List, "Item1", "Item2"))
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.second, new SelectList(ViewBag.List, "Item1", "Item2"), new { disabled = "disabled" })

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#first").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "2") {
                $("#second").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else {
                $("#second").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but currently whenever i change the first drop done; the second drop down will be disabled. can this be due to the fact the the (this).val() will retrieve the ID of the drop down item and not the actual name which is "Virtual Server"?

Comment: @johnG I write a little test and it work. `(this).val()` will return current selected value. is your selectors correct? are you sure that `Virtual Server` is `value` of dropdown(not it's `text`)

Comment: this what i mean , the " Virtul Center " is the text, while the value for the dropdown list is the the Virtual Server ID .

Comment: @johnG Sorry, here, clock is 00:00 and i can't see anything ;) I add a sample to my post, hope this help, but if it doesn't work, please show your dropdown html

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using jQuery.

1. Provide predictable ID properties for the dropdowns, so that you can select them using jQuery
2. Set the disabled property on the second dropdown as default.
3. When the first dropdown is changed, update the disabled property, depending on the selected value.

Here is my complete code, which does this:

### Declaration of dropdowns, and setting default properties:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Role, ((IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.Roles).Select(o => new SelectListItem {
        Text = o, Value = o
    }), new Dictionary<string, object>() {  
        { "id", "rolesDropdown" }
    })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Server, ((IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.Servers).Select(o => new SelectListItem {
        Text = o, Value = o
    }), new Dictionary<string, object>() {  
        { "disabled", "disabled" },
        { "id", "serversDropdown" }
    })
```

### Script to enable/disable the second dropdown, depending on the selected value in the first:

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var rolesDropdown = $("#rolesDropdown");
        var serversDropdown = $("#serversDropdown");

        rolesDropdown.on('change', function (sender, arg) {
            var newVal = $(this).val();
            serversDropdown.attr('disabled', newVal !== "Virtual Server");
        });

    });

</script>
```

Please note that if you haven't already, you have to include jQuery on the page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Initially set the `Virtual Server` drop down list `disabled`.
2. Write a `js function` for `onchange` event for Roles drop down list.
3. In the js function check whether the selected value of the Roles drop down list is 'Virtual Server'.
4. `If true,` `enable` the Virtual Server drop down list.
5. `Else` `disable` the Virtual Server drop down list.